# p:dataTable within ui:repeat breaks the selection of rows

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, datatable

I am using the PrimeFaces(6.1) datatable with in `ui:repeat` or `p:repeat` to display multiple dataTable. Everything renders correctly but dataTable selection alone is not working. How can I achieve this?

NOTE: I have tried with `c:foreach` but it causes some performance issue(takes more time to render page) , but `ui:repeat` loads faster.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{tblcontroller.myList}" var="obj">
    <p:dataTable var="item" value="#{obj.tabllist}"
                 rowSelectMode="add"
                 selection="#{obj.selectedData}" rowKey="#{item.name}">

        <f:facet name="header">#{item.name}</f:facet>

        <p:column selectionMode="multiple"/>
        <p:column headerText="Age" >#{item.age}</p:column>
        <p:column headerText="State" >#{item.state}</p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Country">#{item.country}</p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
    <br/>
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: 'not working' is a little vague. What does it do? Do you see the correct setters being called? Tried accessing the 'obj' via the rowIndexVar that you can use on the repeat? so something like `selection="#{tblcontroller.myList[objIndex].selectedData}" ?

Comment: @Kukeltje if i chage the UI repeat to c:foreach its working.

Comment: I never mentioned c:foreach in my comment